# undefined reference to `DAQmxCreateTask@8

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, dll, lib, nidaqmx

By using VS code, I was trying to build a C code which has a DAQmx library from National Instruments. I have already included the NIDAQmx.h header file to the code. even if the build was successful, while compiling the code I am getting error messages regarding undefined reference to DAQmx functions.

find my code below,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\Shared\ExternalCompilerSupport\C\include\NIDAQmx.h"

TaskHandle taskHandle=0;
int ret=0;
int main()
{
    printf("Hello world");
    ret=DAQmxCreateTask("task",&taskHandle);
    printf("Return for creating task is %d\n",ret);
    DAQmxStopTask (taskHandle); 
    DAQmxClearTask(taskHandle);
    printf("Task closed ");
}
```

my console output as follows,

```
[Running] cd "d:\Documents\mydaq\src\" && gcc mydaq.c -o mydaq && "d:\Documents\mydaq\src\"mydaq
C:\Users\Remya\AppData\Local\Temp\cc88k2NN.o:mydaq.c:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `DAQmxCreateTask@8'
C:\Users\Remya\AppData\Local\Temp\cc88k2NN.o:mydaq.c:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `DAQmxStopTask@4'
C:\Users\Remya\AppData\Local\Temp\cc88k2NN.o:mydaq.c:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `DAQmxClearTask@4'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.421 seconds
```

my tasks. Json file as follows.

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "mydaq.c",
                "-o",
                "mydaq.exe",
                "-LC:\\Program Files (x86)\\National Instruments\\Shared\\ExternalCompilerSupport\\C\\lib32\\msvc",
                "-lNIDAQmx"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Build finished successful in VS Code terminal as follows,

```
Starting build...
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -g mydaq.c -o mydaq.exe "-LC:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\Shared\ExternalCompilerSupport\C\lib32\msvc" -lNIDAQmx

Build finished successfully.
```

Comment: The shown console output doesn't not correspond to tasks.json. Ensure it's written on disk.

Comment: it's the output I am getting while running the code by run code option in the right click.